# How to upgrade Yesod to the latest version?

Tags: haskell, ubuntu, yesod

After I did a

```
cabal install yesod
```

I did a

```
yesod version
```

But it outputs 0.10.2.1. The latest version I believe is 1.3

How do I upgrade to the latest version? I'm trying to set yesod on an Ubuntu server.

Comment: Is the `~/.cabal/bin` directory in the path? If not, you may have the latest there but the shell only finds the one in `/usr[/local]/bin`. If yes, what version of cabal-install have you, and what does `cabal install -v2 yesod --dry-run` say?

Comment: Daniel Fischer's comment looks plausible. Perhaps a query with `which` would tell you where it's finding the binary...

Comment: ~/.cabal/bin wasn't in my path, so I added it. When I did which yesod, it returned the old version. I removed that file, so now when I do which yesod, it doesn't return anything. However if I do cabal install yesod, it tells me that version 1.1.2 is already installed. Any ideas?

Comment: After adding it to the path, have you started a new shell? Or `export`ed the new path?

Comment: I did both, but I'm still getting "The program 'yesod' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install yesod" when I type "yesod"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deal with installed packages there is ghc-pkg, so to remove yesod

```
ghc-pkg unregister yesod
```

This don't remove executables, so

```
rm ~/.cabal/bin/yesod
```

Then update the package list

```
cabal update
```

Then cabal install will select the latest version compatible (based on the "base" package dependency) with your ghc version (if I am not wrong)

```
cabal install yesod
```

Comment: I followed these steps and yesod apparently installed correctly, but I got the message "The program 'yesod' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install yesod". When I do echo $PATH, ~/.cabal/bin is not there. I guess now the question is how to permanently add it to my path in Ubuntu... However, shouldn't it work when I browse to ~/cabal/bin? For some reason it gives me the same error.

Comment: @DiegoSaa To get it into the path permanently, add it to the path (if not yet present) in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`, whichever Ubuntu uses. Something along the lines of `if [ -z `/bin/echo ${PATH} | /usr/bin/grep cabal` ]\nthen\n    export PATH=/home/diego/.cabal/bin:$PATH\nfi` (the '\n' should be actual newlines, and replace "diego" with whatever your username is. But also try if invoking `~/.cabal/bin/yesod` works to check whether you cabal-installed a working binary.

Answer (score 0):

Add cabal installed packages to your path:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.cabal/bin":$PATH
```

*into the terminal.*

This means you can run yesod as `yesod` rather than:

```
~/.cabal/bin/yesod
```